# Comparing two Lists of same type of Objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

Assume I have two lists, now listOld contains old Employee information, listNew contains new Employee information

```
Employee {
   long lastUpdate;
}

List<Employee> listOld; //ArrayList
List<Employee> listNew;
```

How do I compare both the lists and return new List which contains, the list of new Employees added, new List which contains, the list of employees removed, new List which contains the Employees whose lastUpdate has changed?

I could only think of iterating over lists and comparing, could end up almost O(n2) time and could this be done by any util class and more efficiently?

Comment: Apache commons CollectionUtils can solve the first two cases, if u think it is appropriate to use that library.

Comment: If you care for performance: you should be aware of that these util classes often still do the same you would do - meaning its not necessarily faster using a apache commons rather than implementing it on your own

Comment: If you consider speed, you can convert your list into hash tables first and then use the collection library on them. This should bring you down from O(n^2) to something between O(n) and O(n*ln(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's commons.collections library has a CollectionUtils class.
The class  provides methods for Collection checking, including intersection, difference, and union.

See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html